# Pygame transparency issue

Tags: python, pygame, transparency, transparent

I have a rather confusing problem. I currently have a countdown and I would ideally have the text from the countdown to be somewhat transparent (say 50% or so)

```
    pygame.init()
    surface = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0))
    fontObj = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 600)
    textSurfaceObj = fontObj.render("3", True, (255, 255, 255))
    textRectObj = textSurfaceObj.get_rect()
    textRectObj.center = (surface.get_width() / 2, surface.get_height() / 2)
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

while True:
    surface.fill(255, 255, 255)
    pygame.display.update()

    time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    filename = 'photos/' + time.replace(' ', '_') + '.jpg'
    for i in xrange(3, 0, -1):
            surface.fill(WHITE)
            textSurfaceObj = fontObj.render(str(i), True, (255, 0, 0)
            surface.blit(textSurfaceObj, textRectObj)
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.wait(1000)
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.wait(100);
            surface.fill(WHITE)
            pygame.display.update()
```

I've tried putting in `surface.set_alpha(50)` but that doesnt seem to do anything. Any suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: have you tried doing textSurfaceObj.set_alpha(50)?

Comment: thank you for your quick reply! I have not, but after trying, it didnt yield any result.

Comment: try adding .convert() to the end of the font render i.e.:`textSurfaceObj = fontObj.render(str(i), True, (255, 0, 0).convert()` and still setting the alpha for that surface.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Sadly this turns my red text into a fully filled red rectangle block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pygame you must set a background color for antialiased text if you want it to use a color key (which allows you to render transparent text). To get the result you want you just need to match the background color to the surface color, in this case white. The below code (starting right after the for i in ...) worked for me:

```
surface.fill(WHITE)
textSurfaceObj = fontObj.render(str(i), True, (255, 0, 0),WHITE)
textSurfaceObj.set_alpha(50)
surface.blit(textSurfaceObj,(0,0))
pygame.display.update()
pygame.time.wait(500)
```

Edit: I did a little digging as to what's going on here, and [this mailing list post](http://archives.seul.org/pygame/users/Nov-2001/msg00098.html) details the backend properties that cause this for anyone interested.

Comment: You're absolutly right, this fixed it for me! Thank you.